# Docker - copying JAR file: no such file or directory?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, docker, gradle, jar

I have the following `Dockerfile` for a very simple `spring boot` REST application:

```
# Prepare runtime.
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

# Prepare build workspace.
FROM gradle:5.3.0-jdk-alpine AS sdk
WORKDIR /build-workspace

# Setup build workspace.
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle .
USER gradle

# Copy.
COPY build.gradle .
COPY gradle.properties .
COPY src ./src

# Build, Test and publish.
RUN gradle clean bootJar

# App image.
FROM runtime
COPY --from=sdk /build-workspace/build/libs/myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

My docker file is in the root directory of my project, beside `build.gradle` etc.

when I run:

```
docker build -t myApplication .
```

I get the error:

> Step 14/15 : COPY --from=sdk
>   /build-workspace/build/libs/myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar
>       COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e9441fe0b968bd5776ee860bbca780d6c2037fcf90cb67d01c3b1fd349d3996f/merged/build-workspace/build/libs/myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:
>   no such file or directory

What am I doing wrong in my docker file?

Comment: Could you please try to build the jar locally and copy it using docker file? Just to be sure that gradle clean bootJar is not failing? Everything looks fine and the only reason seems there is no jar, which might due to the jar building step is not working.

Comment: what is the output of this step RUN gradle clean bootJar

Comment: The `docker build` sequence will also print out a series of hex numbers; these are valid image IDs and you can `docker run` any of them to see what's inside the image as it's being built.

Comment: @GAK the gradle clean bootJar is working fine as expected, it only fails at the COPY

Comment: I understand the bootJar command ran well. But where does it creates the file. The COPY command is not able to reach that location. Thats why i wanted the output of the build jar command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `RUN ls -l /build-workspace/build/libs/` after the `RUN gradle clean bootJar` to see what’s in that directory.